# How do I escape backslash in R using gsub?

Tags: r, gsub

How do you replace a "backslash" by nothing in a string ?

I'm doing this :

```
A = "plot_maker(df,c(\"var1\", \"var2\"))"
gsub("\\\\","11", A)
```

it's not working

I would like to have something like this at the end :

```
plot_maker(df,c("var1", "var2"))
```

Comment: there aren't any backslashes in your example, just escaped apostrophes

Comment: I think you're looking for `eval(parse(text = A))`

Comment: Use `cat(A)` to verify that there are no backslashes in your output. R just has to escape special characters when printing the value. Using `cat()` avoid the special escaping. But this is for visual output only. The string itself contains no slashes, it just contains quotes inside quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You're confused by the distinction between a string and the way it is displayed by R. Your string doesn't actually have any backslashes in it, but R is adding them when it displays.  You can see this with

```r
print(A, quote = FALSE)
## [1] plot_maker(df,c("var1", "var2"))
```

or

```r
cat(A, "\n")
## plot_maker(df,c("var1", "var2"))
```

(the `\n` is added to print a newline after the string)